# Почему ошибка (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код:

```
import os

def get_ip_address(url):
    command = 'host' + url
    process = os.popen(command)
    results = str(process.read())
    marker = results.find('has address') + 12
    return results[marker:].splitlines()[0]


print(get_ip_address('google.com'))
```

Ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\Karen\Desktop\PocketSploit\modules\ip_address.py", line 9, in get_ip_address
    return results[marker:].splitlines()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: возможно вы используете ОС Windows, которая не имеет такой комманды (host). потому с точки синтаксиса всё правильно, но на выходе в переменной results нет ничего так как она равна None

Comment: Что за команда (host)? Что ты хочешь получить вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, `process.read()` возвращает пустую строку.

Пример для воспроизведения ошибки:

```
In [19]: results = str("")

In [20]: marker = results.find('has address') + 12

In [21]: marker
Out[21]: 11

In [22]: results[marker:].splitlines()
Out[22]: []

In [23]: results[marker:].splitlines()[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-6962e431f3ce> in <module>()
----> 1 results[marker:].splitlines()[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

когда Вы определяете переменную "command", она становится равной `hostgoogle.com`, подозреваю, что нужно получить `host google.com`, попробуйте заменить `command = 'host' + url` на `command = 'host ' + url`.